# Find out for how long the script was running for in seconds?

Tags: php, while-loop, microtime

I have a script which runs in a '**while**' cycle. I need to determine for how long the script was running for and if it is over 10 seconds terminate it. The code I wrote returns weird decimal values **(one second it might be '5.342...' and other it might be '903.322...')**.
Can someone tell me how can I achieve that?

```
$timer = microtime(false);
while(/*...*/)
{
   $currTime = microtime(false);
   $timeDiff = $currTime - $timer;
   $timeDiff *= 1000;

   if ($timeDiff > 10)
   {
      //...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're tracking microseconds. If you want to see only the seconds, round it
up using [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) or [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php).

You might also consider [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), which controls how long the script is allowed to run for.

```
set_time_limit(10); // allow ten seconds for this script to finish
```

You can use [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to handle any cleanup that is necessary if the script didn't finish in time.

Comment: Won't multiplying it by 1000 do it?

Comment: No, multiplying by 1000 won't necessarily ensure a non-fraction result: `3.29381 * 1000 = 3293.81`

Comment: The whole point is that I must not let this thing trigger an error. So I must make sure that the script terminates if it reaches 10 seconds.

Comment: Nick, you can use `register_shutdown_function()` to handle things if the script didn't finish in time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$timeDiff /= 1000;
```

1000 microseconds is a second, not the other way around

Answer (score 1):

I believe the argument should be true, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Try:

```
$timer = microtime(true);
while(true)
{
   $currTime = microtime(true);
   $timeDiff = $currTime - $timer;

   if ($timeDiff > 10)
   {
      die();
   }
}
```

Comment: It will not be accurate down to the milisecond though - only +/- a second.